# Consolidating Documentation Fragments on one page

Tags: doxygen

I would like to consolidate documentation fragments on one page.

My use case is I have two different source modules where I want to put a doxygen fragment.  Then in a third source module I want to put a @page that references the fragments.

My hope is that when the doc is generated I will see those 5 fragments consolidated onto one .html page.

The page/subpage system does not work because that just puts links on a page to the documentation fragments.  I want the fragments consolidated onto one page.

This is the first .c file:

```
/*! @setfrag FRAG1
** this is some text for fragment 1
*/
```

This is a second file:

```
/*! @setfrag FRAG2
** This is some text for fragment 2.
*/
```

This is a third file:

```
/*! @page SOMEPAGE Page demonstrates consolidating fragments.
** @getfrag FRAG1
** @getfrag FRAG2
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right, but this should be exactly what grouping does. You can define a "group" using the tag `@defgroup groupname description` and then add the fragments to the group using the tag `@addtogroup groupname`. 
Then you would define your group in any file (e.g. you could create a seperate file "groups.dox"):

```
/**
 * @defgroup myGroup My Group
 * @brief A brief description of \"My Group\"
 * @details A more detailed description of \"My Group\".
 */
```

Them you can add fragments or complete files to this group by adding the following to the files:

```
/**
 * @addtogroup myGroup
 * @{
 */

// any contents you want to add to the group 

/**
 * @}
 */
```

This results in a tab called "Modules" where each group is listed as a "Module" with its own page. If you want to add the whole file documentation to the group ensure that you also enclose the `@file` tag  with the `@{` and `@}` tags.